# Running `.pyc` file in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, pyc

One of the great things about `%run` magic command is that allows you to run any python script and load all of its data directly into the interactive namespace.

However, the same approach does not work for `.pyc` file.

Is there a way to run  `.pyc` file from jupyter notebook  and load its data directly into the interactive namespace?

The goal is to prevent the user from editing, reading and modifying the source code.

Comment: I think the best approach here would be to deny the user the relevant permissions.